# ASP.NET control for reCAPTCHA not working in Opera

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I use ASP.NET reCAPTCHA control on my website (.net 3.5). I got it from [this site](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/aspnet.html) (version 1.0.4.0).

It works great in IE6, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, but I don't know why it doesn't work in Opera. When I open the page, it's blank. I use Opera 10.62.

I've prepared just a simple web form which contains only the reCAPTCHA control. The markup is:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClientWebPortal.test" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" PublicKey="xxxxx"
        PrivateKey="xxxxxxxx" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem it appears to be a JavaScript exception that causes the image not to load in Opera. Below is the exception that I get:

```
Uncaught exception: [object DOMException]
Error thrown at line 12, column 0 in https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LtestSAAAAAM1MsYg9ktesttestt9niYAftest:
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```